# NLog LogEventInfo.Message is {0} instead of null or empty on custom LayoutRenderer

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a custom `LayoutRenderer`.

If I call the following statement, then I always get `LogEventInfo.Message = {0}` instead of `null` or `""`. Did I missunderstand something?

```
try
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    var c = a / b;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    logger.Error(e);
}

public class HtLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        // logEvent.Message is {0} instead of being null or empty ""
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Update 1 - added full example code

I only posted a very small example.

I have two custom `Exceptions`: `HtReturnStatus` and `HtExceptions`. Both of them are of type `Exception`. `HtReturnStatus` can contains `HtExceptions`. `HtLayoutRenderer` is unpacking the objects and making a convience logging layout. It shouldn't matter what Type of class/object is supplied.

My problem is the `{0}`. When this is the *normal behavior*, then I would check if `logEvent.Message` is `{0}` and ignore it.

```cs
try
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    var c = a / b;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LayoutRenderer.Register<HtLayoutRenderer>("htmessage");

    TraceTarget target = new TraceTarget();
    target.Name = "console";
    target.Layout = Layout.FromString("${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${logger} | ${htmessage}");
    LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
    LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(target);
    LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Insert(0, new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.FromString("Trace"), target));
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    logger.Error("1");
    logger.Error(e);
    logger.Error("2");
    logger.Error(e, "Hello World");
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("3");
    logger.Error(HtReturnStatus.Failed(e), "Lorem Ipsum");
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("4");
    logger.Error(HtReturnStatus.Failed(e, "Error on division"));
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("5");
    logger.Error(HtReturnStatus.Failed(HtErrorCode.OPC_BAD_CERTIFICATE_INVALID));
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("6");
    logger.Error(HtReturnStatus.Failed(HtErrorCode.OPC_BAD_UNEXPECTED_ERROR, "Error on division #2"));

    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("7");
    logger.Error(new HtException(HtErrorCode.CODE_READER_DMC_MultipleMatches));
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("8");
    logger.Error(new HtException(HtErrorCode.CODE_READER_DMC_MultipleMatches, "hello world"));
    logger.Error("");
    logger.Error("9");
    logger.Error(new HtException(HtErrorCode.CODE_READER_DMC_MultipleMatches, "lorem ipsum", e));
}
```

```
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1168 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 1
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1383 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - Attempted to divide by zero. - System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1572 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 2
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1572 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | Hello World - Attempted to divide by zero. - System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1572 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1572 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 3
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1742 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | Lorem Ipsum - System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1742 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1742 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 4
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1742 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - Error on division - System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1905 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.1905 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 5
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2166 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - Haprotec.Error.HtException: 563021 (OPC_BAD_CERTIFICATE_INVALID)
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2204 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2204 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 6
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2204 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - Error on division #2 - Haprotec.Error.HtException: 563001 (OPC_BAD_UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2204 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2204 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 7
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2374 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - Haprotec.Error.HtException: 500251 (CODE_READER_DMC_MultipleMatches)
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2374 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2374 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 8
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2374 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - hello world - Haprotec.Error.HtException: 500251 (CODE_READER_DMC_MultipleMatches)
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2374 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2506 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | 9
testhost Error: 0 : 2020-01-21 10:14:01.2506 | ERROR | Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest | {0} - lorem ipsum - System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
StackTrace:    at Haprotec.Error.NLogOutputTest.HtReturnStatusOutputTest() in D:\Repositories\gitlab.haprotec\dotNet\HtCore\src\HtCore.Tests\Error\NLogOutputTest.cs:line 26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fully intentional. You are calling this logger-method, where one is logging a random object:

```
Logger.Error<T>(T value);
```

This is shorthand for this, that ensures `string.Format` will work:

```
Logger.Error("{0}", value);
```

But you have probably noticed that special handling has been implemented for `Exception`. NLog performs extra checking to capture the Exception-parameter for `${exception}`, but doesn't change the format-string.

In your `HtLayoutRenderer` then you can recognize it like this:

```
public class HtLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
       if ( logevent.Exception != null
         && logevent.Message == "{0}"
         && logevent.Parameters?.Length == 1
         && ReferenceEquals(logevent.Exception, logevent.Parameters[0])
       {
          // Exception given as single parameter without any message
       }
    }
}
```

Notice that there is a difference between `LogEventInfo.Message` and `LogEventInfo.FormattedMessage`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I have added a more complex example to my post. Maybe you can see what I want to do and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @DominicJonas Updated my answer with an example of how you can recognize, that Exception was given a single parameter without any message.